# Froala editor suddenly not responding properly: missing spaces

Tags: froala

The strangest thing happened. My froala rich text fields (Rails app) stopped working afer I committed some other work.

The symptoms were the following:

- In Firefox, I could not enter spaces, only letters would appear as I typed
- In Chrome, spaces showed, but I could not create new lines
- None of the formatting toolbar buttons worked (bold, italics, etc)

(Used for rails form fields that require rich text. Licensed version.)

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that some Javascript must have clobbered a Froala method?

The following code was in a javascript file in our code base:

```
var getSelection = function(){...
```

Once I renamed the method, everything worked perfectly.

```
var getHydrantSelection = function(){...
```

The code relying on the new method, and the Froala editor code were both working again!

(Shrug. Probably a better way to scope the JS?)

Answer (score -1):

I am one of the makers of the Froala Editor. It looks like you're using the Froala Editor V1. The editor JS is scoped and it is strange that you're getting this conflict. Do you have any methods in your JS which override the getSelection method somehow?

Comment: I was a little surprised that the JS methods were not scoped. What can I show you to help answer your curiosity?